# Twig escape tag

Tags: php, twig

I have two questions, one is about name of tag in Twig code syntax, and other one is about how to modify this tag.

Tag: `{{ 'Some text' }}` or `{{ "Some text" }}`

In both examples it will display "Some text", but I want to use my function (`translate()` ) before display. I don't know where I should search in code, because I don't even know name this tag.

I want to translate parsed text before display, e.g.: `{{ 'Some text' }}` -> `<?php echo translate('Some text'); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own `Twig extenstion`. Tutorial is available [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html). It's the most elegant way.

Extension:

```
class Translate_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension
{    
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'translate' => \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'translate', array('is_safe' => array('html'))) 
        );
    }

    public function translate($text)
    {
        // do the magic, return translated text
    }
}
```

Template:

```
{{ translate('some text') }}
```